# sorting the data ignoring the header in csv in python

Tags: python

I wrote a code to sort the data on first 5 columns which is a csv file(pipe separator).

```
import csv
import operator
with open('DDD_Strips_by_Sub_Channel_final.csv',mode='r') as f, 
open('DDD_Strips_by_Sub_Channel_sorted.csv','w') as final:
    writer = csv.writer(final, delimiter='|')
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    header=next(reader,None)
    next(reader)
    sorted1 = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]))
    if header:
        writer.writerow(header)
    for row in sorted1:
       writer.writerow(row)
```

Its sorting the data properly, but the output file generating by inserting new line between each row

[image]

can any one please help in getting the proper output without extra lines.

Comment: Dont you consider Pandas? this is pretty easy and nice for this Job?

Comment: @Supriya Are you using python 2 or 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `python 2.x` then you must open the file using `wb` mode instead of `w`. So it will become `open('DDD_Strips_by_Sub_Channel_sorted.csv','wb')`

Change your line to this,

```
with open('DDD_Strips_by_Sub_Channel_final.csv',mode='rb') as f, 
open('DDD_Strips_by_Sub_Channel_sorted.csv','wb') as final:
```

If you are using `python 3.x` then you need to use `newline` parameter `open('DDD_Strips_by_Sub_Channel_sorted.csv','w', newline='')`

Hope that fixed your problem.

Comment: I am using python 2.x

Comment: @SupriyaRapelli Updated my answer, Let me know if it worked.